# Login e Cadastro na mesma pagina - laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, login

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web usando o laravel 5.2 e usei o make:auth para gerar o sistema de login do laravel, mais me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Estou querendo usar na mesma pagina de login o formulário de cadastro porém quando clico no submit de ambos as mensagens de erros aparecem para ambos os inputs e se preencho o form de cadastro o mesmo direciona para /register tentando se logar.

como poderia estar resolvendo isto?

Obrigado.

Comment: Encontrei a solução neste post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097071/laravel-login-and-register-forms-on-the-same-page-in-laravel-5-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097071/laravel-login-and-register-forms-on-the-same-page-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: Têm coo enviar um exemplo do código para que possa clarear mais sua dúvida?

Comment: Vlws pedro já consegui resolver o problema encontrei uma solução em um post.

Comment: Douglas podias criar uma resposta aqui, em Português e bem explicada. Asssim fica conteúdo útil para outros que tenham o mesmo problema.